# Why is my iPad app failing to validate?

Tags: xcode, ipad, validation

I would very much appreciate some assistance with this problem. I am trying to validate my iPad app and I'm getting an error 'unable to process app at this time due to a general error'. Also, in the organiser, the icon isn't appearing at the top. I have seen a similar issue in an earlier version of XCode but that was a while ago now. It has been failing for two days now so I doubt it's an Apple issue with traffic.
I have copied images of some of my settings here:
http://mrwakeling.com/Help
Perhaps it's a problem with the way I've named some of my bundles/executables? It was throwing that up as an error in earlier archives so I tried changing them - it doesn't give that error now, just the above one.
Thank you in advance and thanks for reading this.
Edit: I also changed the name of my app recently, could this have had an effect?

Comment: Did you ever get a solution to this? I am having the same error

Comment: Yes I had to mess about with no help though! :) have you changed your executable file name from its default?